# How can I provide live replication of a Linux server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, replication

I need to be able to do live replication of a running Ubuntu server, so if the main machine goes down I can automatically failover to the other machine.  I found mklivecd, but that seems to only get me to having a current backup. While that's certainly close, what I really want is to know that everything is already installed on the other machine live.  Is there another utility I can pair up with mklivecd, or is there a better way?

Update: This is a web and database server, with files (ie images) that are added throughout the day.  DRDB looks like it might do the job; we'll look into it.  Thank you all very much!

Comment: You want to do live replication of a complete system or just it's data ?

Comment: What you need to do to reach your goal is dependent on the services you offer from the server. E.g., a file server has different requirements to offer a fail over than a DNS or LDAP server.

Anyway, a guide to a complete solution is out of the scope of this site, but we can help with specific problems of your implementation, and we could give you a few hints about what to look for if you extend your question a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like [DRDB](http://www.drbd.org/) or rsync in a frequent cron. I'd choose DRDB, personally.

mklivecd is certainly not the right tool for this job, dont even try to make it fit.

Edit: I just saw that you updated saying this is a database and web server. You'll want to use your DBMS' replication engine for that and use DRDB for the web content. You shouldn't use DRDB for live databases.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for revamping a so old thread but I have a question. If the server includes open SQLite database files, how to perform replication, provided that SQLite doesn't offer any built-in feature for that?